# SAS Create permanent format from permanent dataset

Tags: dataset, format, sas

I have a permanent data set called Branch(Branch code, Branch description)

I want to create a format from that dataset (a permanent one)

I can see that this gives me more or less what I want, but now to put it into a permanent dataset?

```
proc format library = Home.Branch fmtlib;
Run;
```

What I've tried

```
  proc print data=Home.DataSetToApply
  format B_Code $B_CODE_FORMAT.;
  RUN;
```

This works if I manually create the format. I can't seem to create a permanent format directly from a data set.
Could you point me in the right direction?

Resources 
[Creating a Format from Raw Data or a SAS® Dataset](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/068-2007.pdf)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will create a dataset with formats in the current library.

```
proc format cntlout=myfmtdataset lib=mylibname;
select myformatname; *if you want to just pick one or some - leave out select for all;
quit;
```

This will import that back into formats (later):

```
proc format cntiln=myfmtdataset lib=myotherlibname;
quit;
```

That could of course be in your autoexec, or in your regular code.

If you are trying to take a dataset to make a permanent format, you need to set it up like this:

Required:

- fmtname = name of format start   = starting value (or, single value)
- end     = ending value (this can be missing if only single values)
- label   = formatted value

Optional:

- type    = type of format (n=numeric, c=character, i=informat, j=character informat)
- hlo     = various options (h=end is highest value, l = start is lowest value,
  o=other, m=multilabel, etc.)

Then use the CNTLIN option to load it.  SAS documentation has more detail if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

SAS has an autoexec.sas file which executes when you start SAS.
Of course, whether this is a valid option depends on your access rights + the OS you're running.

Have a look here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-sysop-autoexec.htm

You could just drop the format code in the auto-executing script then to have your format always available when using SAS.

Comment: Is that the only way to do it? Does this mean that there isn't a way to just convert a data set to a format permanently?

Comment: you can modify your format search path in your sasv9.cfg file.  Alternatively, you can add the library to the search path in the autoexec (no need to recreate).  See this http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lesysoptsref/64892/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1fvn6rwmpf1njn1whkud1hmsc97.htm